# Customize YouTube thumbnail, returned by getclickToPlayButton

Tags: flash, youtube-api

Is there a way to customize the thumbnail returned by `getclickToPlayButton` from the [YouTube Flash API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference?hl=pl#getClickToPlayButton)? I need to add a layer with a "play" icon

Currently I am using a flash player, with a custom miniature to play the video, using the player.playVideo() method, but the displays are not counted in YouTube. This is why I want to switch to `getclickToPlayButton`.

Regards,
Marek

Comment: That thumbnail is chosen by the video owner ... it's the "hqfedault" thumb that they set.

Comment: jlmcdonald - I know that, but I can not edit the thumbnail

Comment: So this is your video, then? If so, you can upload a custom thumbnail as long as your account has been verified: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431?hl=en given you instructions on how to verify your account and then how to upload your own custom thumbnail.

Comment: I know "how to change" the thumbnail, but I'm not allowed to do that, because it will change the main thumbnail displayed also in YouTube.com (and I don't want to do that). I need to customize it from the flash player. Also the video can be embeded in other web pages, where I don't want "my" customization.

Comment: So that's where I come back to my original comment. The getClickToPlayButton method, by its definition, returns the hqdefault thumb. It will always return that thumb, and there is no method for supplying that method a different thumb at runtime (nor is there a different method in the YouTube Player API for putting a different image there). Your only choice would be to provide your own poster thumb with HTML, and then when that's clicked on execute a script that hides the poster and shows your player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Youtube thumbnail & play icon containers are referenced respectively as: `thumb_MC` and `Play_icon_MC`...

> I need to add a layer with a "play" icon...

Did you try to addChild the `Play_icon_MC` only **after** you addChild the `thumb_MC` container (MClip/Sprite)? This way it's automatically on a layer above the thumbnail since its the most recent added `displayObject`. The problem now will be how do you click the `thumb_MC` if the `Play_icon_MC` is above it? For that make sure in the code where you add Play_icon_MC add this line shwn below:

`Play_icon_MC.mouseEnabled = false;`

Also the function that actually handles the thumbnail click should then hide the Play_icon_MC. It would be brought back (visibility boolean? alpha amount?) by whatever function you got for handling video ending/stopped etc..

Comment: Thanks! `mouseEnabled` is exactly what I need :)